# electron add onclick dynamically fails

Tags: electron

I try to add elements dynamically in the render process like the following:

```
import {remote, ipcRenderer} from 'electron'
var userResponseString = ipcRenderer.sendSync('getUserData');
var userResponseData = JSON.parse(userResponseString)
parseTeams(userResponseData.teams);
function parseTeams(teamArray) {
  let teams = document.getElementById('teams')
  teamArray.forEach(element => {
    let item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = element[1];
    // item.onclick = function(){
    //   ipcRenderer.sendSync('getTeamData', {id:element[0]})
    // }
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      ipcRenderer.sendSync('getTeamData', {id:element[0]})
    })
    teams.append(item)
  });
}
```

However, neither setting onclick nor addEventListener works. Elements are edit, texts are shown, but not clickable. What is the proper way to do this? Many thanks.

Comment: I have just used same code replacing ipcRenderer.sendSync with a console.log and it worked, can you check if there are any console errors in your code which is causing issue with event binding.

Comment: sorry for the late response, you are right, the problem is from the receiver getTeamData function in main.js